# Is is possible to detect event attaching/detaching security group from AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am looking for a way to detect events when you detach/attach security group from EC Instance. I tried to use Cloudtrail but there are only events when you modify Security Group (edit/delete/create rules) something likes *AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress, AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress, CreateSecurityGroup, DeleteSecurityGroup*

I appreciate any help
Thank you

Comment: There is [aws config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html) which you clould use to monitor your instance whether they have or don't have specific security groups. The Config would detect when the instances break your rules (.e.g. when SG is detached, or incorrect one is attached) and perform action on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple ways to do this:

- As mentioned above AWS Config can be used to monitor constant changes in resources. There is a existing rule for [adding a security group rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/ec2-security-group-attached-to-eni.html). You would need to add a [Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config_develop-rules_getting-started.html) for any custom rules.
- It is possible to use CloudWatch events with AWS API call via CloudTrail for this, you would need to set event name as the api call name (either modify-instance-attribute or modify-network-interface-attribute would be used).

Out of personal preference I would suggest AWS config as the way forward, CloudTrail events can take around 15 minutes so they will always be a little out of sync.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use AWS config for that